# How to get desired results in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I use this query to fetch:
customername from tblcustomers
sum of transactionamount from tbltransactions against each customer

```
select a.customerid, sum(transactionamount) as transactionamount ,b.customername
from tbltransactions a 
join tblcustomers b using (customerid) 
group by a.customerid 
order by b.customername
```

the coloumn `transactionamount` in `tbltransactions` contains positive values for customer purchases and negative values for customer payments.

how to get this expression in this query **min(transactionamount) < 0 for each customer**?

**EDIT: min(transactionamount) < 0 gives me the maximum amount paid so far by each customer**

Comment: Explain your intention by words, your attempt doesn't clarify what you want.

Comment: `having max(transactionamount) < 0` after groupy by may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select a.customerid, sum(transactionamount) as transactionamount, b.customername,
       min(case when transactionamount < 0 then transactionamount end) as BiggestPayment
from tbltransactions a join
     tblcustomers b
     using (customerid)
group by a.customerid
order by b.customername;
```

Note the smallest value less than 0 is really the minimum not the maximum.

EDIT:

In this case, I would find the latest payment date using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
substring_index(group_concat((case when transactionamount < 0 then transactionamount end)
                              order by transactiondate desc
                            ), ',', 1)
```

Comment: how could we further modify this query to find the latest transactionid where transactionamount < 0 ???? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where to fit this one in the query ... I'm new to sql :)

Comment: @user3762808 . . . Just add the expression to the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
select a.customerid, sum(transactionamount) as transactionamount ,b.customername 
from tbltransactions a 
join tblcustomers b using (customerid) 
group by a.customerid 
having max(transactionamount) < 0
order by b.customername
```

to sum only customer with only payments?

Best regards,
Nebojsa